# Lucene query documents that don't have a specific field

Tags: lucene

I am using `Lucene` in android to search my content. I have two types of documents and one has a `trashed` field which is either `true` or `false`. The other type of document does not have that field. I want to return all documents that have `trashed:false`, or don't have the `trashed` field.

I have tried add `-trashed:true` to my query, which returns all the correct documents, but it messes up the offsets of the search surround a different word and not the one I am searching for.

EDIT:

I have to add this to every search query I perform.  I have an index of approximately 20,000 documents and I would really like to not have to rebuild it because I had my users rebuild their indices my last release.  Note: this is on android devices so it takes a long time and a lot of battery to reindex all of their documents.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "it messes up the offsets of the search surround a different word and not the one I am searching for" ?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of following solution.

1) If you can rebuild the index.

Add trashed:na field-value to the docs for which "trashed" is not applicable.

To get all the docs with trashed:false or "trashed" is not applicable, you can use following..

Query:  trashed:false OR trashed:na

2) If you cannot rebuild the index, I am not sure...

Comment: Unfortunately rebuilding my index is not a possibility.

Comment: @Ge3ng Lucene provides a way to "search" fields... I don't think we can retrieve a document if that "field" doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: @Ge3ng It might be possible to find a workaround if you can elaborate.. 
- index stats (size, terms), how often do you have to find docs in the way you've specified, may be more info...

Comment: @Ge3ng, btw, can you add a new document to the Index..?